# asynchronous function doesn't return data

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I wrote a function to fetch an `NSDictionary` from a URL.

```
[Data loadFromAPI:@"http://example.com/api" withSuccess:^(id data) {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = (NSDictionary *)data;

    CLS_LOG(@"result: %@", result);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    CLS_LOG(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The function it calls is the one below:

```
typedef void (^Success)(id data);
typedef void (^Failure)(NSError *error);

+ (void)loadFromAPI:(NSString *)apiURL withSuccess:(Success)success failure:(Failure)failure {
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURL]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];

    request = [mutableRequest copy];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [JSONResponseSerializerWithData serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)responseObject ;

        NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [self now], @"time",
                               jsonArray, @"response",
                               nil];

        CLS_LOG(@"Result is: %@", result);

        success(result);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failure?failure(error):nil;
    }];

    [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [operationQueue addOperations:@[operation] waitUntilFinished:NO];
}
```

Inside the function `CLS_LOG(@"Result is: %@", result);` returns the data returned. However, where I call the function `CLS_LOG(@"result: %@", result);` returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you assigning a `NSDictionary` to a `NSMutableDictionary` in this line: `NSMutableDictionary *result = (NSDictionary *)data;`

Comment: [self now]? where is that?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out `[self now]` returned `null`, so the `NSDictionary` wasn't being set properly.

Comment: @user4486205 then what you mean by "Inside the function CLS_LOG(@"Result is: %@", result); returns the data returned"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

`NSMutableDictionary *result = (NSDictionary *)data;`

you cant directly do that, i wonder why you dont have a warning for that..

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data];
```

will probably solve the problem...